# Android chrome gets confused by hashes

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, forms-authentication

This is on Android Chrome, Motorola Moto G (old non 4g version)

I'm using forms authentication. On a session timeout the user is redirected back to the logon page. Assuming the url they were on was :

.../Controller/Index#Section1

they are directed to:

.../Logon?ReturnUrl=/Controller/Index#Section1

On every browser except Android chrome this is fine, on chrome on the logon page none of the textboxs or buttons work, it's as if I wasn't clicking on the page at all

After a fair bit of trial and error I've found I can fix this by stripping off the # section

The problem is that the typical flow will be this

1. session timeout, back to error page
2. Someone hits the backbutton, this takes them to the previous page, forms authentication
   redirects them to the url with the hash in the querystring.

How can I strip out the hash from the forms authentication redirect?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth this is my workaround to the problem. I don't like it but it works for now.

I couldn't remove the hash value, if you set

```
window.location.hash = '' // (or null for that matter)
```

then you get the same problem because the url now looks like 'Index#'

So I changed the hash to one which is on the logon page 'content' which makes the problem go away

```
function TestForAndroidError()
{
    var index = window.location.href.indexOf( '#content' );
    if ( index > -1 )
        return;

    index = window.location.href.indexOf('#');
    if ( index > -1 )
    {           
        // @* We can't seem to remove the hash but we can change it *@
        window.location.hash = 'content';
    }
}

TestForAndroidError();
```